# Fade out, apply css, fade in - JQUERY

Tags: jquery, css, fade

I'm trying to fade out the block on click, thereafter change block position, and Fade In. But it does not work. Here's the code:

```
$("#info-panel").fadeOut("fast");

$("#info-panel").css({
    top: (new pos),
    left: (new pos)
});

$("#info-panel").fadeIn("fast");
```

CSS:

```
#info-panel {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 15px;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #000;
    border: 3px solid #666666;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: Please provide your css and relevant html too

Comment: This means that first of all why css code is executed and then fade out and in

Comment: What is triggering your .click?? I dont see anything that would trigger this, is this a function?

Comment: Yes, click. I did not lay out the rest of the code is the problem here Go out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **callback** function here:

```
$("#info-panel").fadeOut("fast", function () {
    $(this).animate({
        top: (new pos),
        left: (new pos)
    }, "fast", function () {
        // Animation complete.
        $(this).fadeIn("fast");
    });
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/G95Vn/)

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$("#info-panel").fadeOut("fast", function() {
    $(this).css("color", "red"); //Use your CSS here, I did this as an example.
}).fadeIn("fast");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/RPxrS/

Comment: Does not want to change their position

Answer (score 0):

Check how your element is positioned through css see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fposition

Works fine for me in this snippet:

```
#info-panel {
    position:absolute
}

$("#moveme").click(function () {    
    $("#info-panel").fadeOut("fast");

    $("#info-panel").css({
        top: '80px',
        left: '70px'
    });
    $("#info-panel").fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GHXg3/